# Meaning of "청하려하다"

Tags: translation

I have kind of an awkward situation. I asked my Korean friend to correct my sentence. And she did, but she used a word that I can't understand. I looked it up in Naver, but there is no such word. Could you help me out?

My original sentence was:

```
금방 잠자더라도 잠 잘 못 할 거예요.
```

I was corrected:

```
바로 잠을 청하려해도 잠에 들지 못할거예요.
```

So I saw this 청하려하다 word. Naver only has the following:

```
잠을 청하게 하다
```

And it means "to induce sleep."

Could you tell me the meaning of her original word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

청하다 usually means ['to ask'](http://endic.naver.com/krenEntry.nhn?sLn=kr&entryId=ec91b978188d446c97789340758595f3&query=%EC%B2%AD%ED%95%98%EB%A0%A4), e.g for a favor.

However, 잠을 청하다, to 'ask for the favour of sleep', has the idiomatic meaning of '[to try to sleep](http://endic.naver.com/krenIdiom.nhn?sLn=kr&idiomId=088a0d773c3d40cb869609ddbd9d932a&query=%EC%B2%AD%ED%95%98%EB%A0%A4)'.

So 바로 잠을 청하려해도 잠에 들지 못할거예요 means 'if I try to sleep right now, I won't be able to fall asleep'.

Comment: But.. why did she used 청하려하다. what is -려하다 grammar part means? Is it a contraction of 청하려고 하다?

Comment: @LexRomah Yes, it's the same meaning as 려고 하다 - to *intend* to do something. As you can see [here](http://www.koreangrammaticalforms.com/entry.php?eid=0000001113), the '고' is optional. 잠을 청하려 하다 seems almost tautological - it's a bit like "to try to try to sleep" or "to intend to try to sleep".